# Problem in scrolling of listview in samsung galaxy

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app, that has ListView. It is scrolling fine in simulator and HTC device, but scrolling is not working in Samsung Galaxy S and Samsung Vibrant phones, I am getting the reason of this problem, my code is below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/x01_background">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/topgroupwarmup"
               ></ImageView>
        <ListView android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list1" >
        </ListView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/top_solowarmups"
         ></ImageView>
        <ListView android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list2">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: `ListView` has its own scroll. so remove `ScrollView`

Comment: <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
 here use wrap_content for height

Comment: @Adil Soomro, i m not scrolling list view, my need is to scroll images and listviews together. thats why i use scrollview

Comment: when this guy speaks it is authoritative. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3496042#3496042)

Answer (score 0):

try after removing ScrollView tag.......you have used 2 listview then use wrap_content in android:layout_height="fill_parent" in listview node.

Comment: why is problem with samsung galaxy and vibrant only? what is the similarities bw these phones

Answer (score 0):

Both   `ListView`s should `wrap_content`. if that does not work just use a `LinearLayout` to hold your list items.